# Message = null from Oracle database

Tags: php, database, extjs

I am trying to get a message returned from database after updating a form in my app. The updating is working fine but I am getting a null message value from data base when I must be getting "Data was successfully updated".

This is my function:

```
public function UpdatingForm($grupo, $empresa, $departamento)
{
    $sqlGuardaRrhh = "BEGIN
                            StoredProcedure ('".$this->grupo."','".$this->empresa."','".$this->departamento."','".$this->seccion."', '".$this->codigoEmpleado."','".$this->nombreTrabajador."','".$this->apellidoTrabajador."','".$this->cedula."','".$this->cargo."','".$this->fechaNacimiento."', '".$this->genero."','".$this->estadoCivil."','".$this->nacionalidad."','".$this->nivelEstudios."','".$this->tipoSanguineo."','".$this->observaciones."','".$this->ruta."','".$this->numeroEmpleado."',:rc);
                        END;";

    $this->acceso->ejecutarProcedimiento($sqlGuardaRrhh);

    $consulta = $this->acceso->getMatrizCompletaCursor();

    $this->codigoEmpleado = $consulta[0]['V_RESULTADO'];

    //echo $sqlGuardaRrhh;              

    return $this->acceso->getJson(array("success"=> true, "msg"=>$consulta[0]['V_MENSAJE']));
}
```

My database is Oracle and I am using Toad as database controller, when I am executing this procedure directly in toad I am getting the message that is suppose to show but in my app I am getting this as return:

```
{ "success":true, "msg":null }
```

In the database, there is a condition which says that if V_RESULT = Employee Number then return V_MENSAJE= Data was successfully updated.

By the way I am coding in Extjs and I am calling the message like:

```
success: function(form, action) {
   Ext.Msg.show({
                    title:'SGA',
                    msg: action.result.msg,
                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                    icon: Ext.Msg.INFO
                });
},
```

Comment: #1 Your question is missing the crucial part of how you actually try to retrieve the data. You tell us that you use Toad to verify the results, but that by itself is pretty useless as you're obviously not connecting your PHP code with the Toad application, do you?

Comment: #2 ['V_MENSAJE'] is null, but what about the other elements in the array? Maybe this is just a mismap of DB messages to array elements? Can you show a full dump of the $consulta or at least $consulta[0] array?